# How do I make the button value an object, not a string?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my current code. I want the value of the button to be childData and for it to be the original object, not a string so that I can use it appropriately.

```
var childData = childSnapshot.val(); 
                
                document.getElementById("displayChores").innerHTML += (String(childData["clocation"] + " " +
                childData["cname"] + " " +
                childData["cdescription"] + " " +
                childData["ccredits"] + " " +
                childData["cexp"]) + "<br />" +
                "<button class='chorebtn' value= '"+childData+"' onclick=\"choreDone();\">Mission Complete</button><br>")};
```

Answer (score -1):

could you just make a the value of the button a `JSON.stringify()` of the object and then when you want to use it just `JSON.parse()` it back?